# Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'System.IO.DriveInfo'

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 foreach(DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            lstdrive.Items.Add(di.ToString());

        }

     lstfolder.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            DriveInfo drive =(DriveInfo)lstdrive.SelectedItem;
            foreach (DriveInfo diInfo in drive.RootDirectory.GetDirectories())
            {
                lstfolder.Items.Add(diInfo.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
```

error Error 3   Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'System.IO.DriveInfo'

Comment: foreach(DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                lstdrive.Items.Add(di.ToString());
                
            }

Comment: i want both than what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the DriveInfo items to the list this way:

```
foreach (DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    lstdrive.Items.Add(new ListItem(di.ToString(), di.Name));
}
```

and retrieve the selected drive this way:

```
DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo(lstdrive.SelectedValue);

foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in drive.RootDirectory.GetDirectories())
{
    lstfolder.Items.Add(dirInfo.ToString());
}
```

Comment: DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo(lstdrive.SelectedValue);
                foreach (DriveInfo diInfo in drive.RootDirectory.GetDirectories())
                {
                    lstfolder.Items.Add(diInfo.ToString());
                }                                                                                                               Error Cannot convert type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' to 'System.IO.DriveInfo' at foreach

Comment: Inside the `foreach`, the variable `diInfo` should be of type `DirectoryInfo`, not `DriveInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

You got this error at

```
 DriveInfo drive =(DriveInfo)lstdrive.SelectedItem;
```

You can avoid this error by creating a class like

```
public class MyLi: ListItem
{
    public DriveInfo DI { get; set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return DI.ToString();
    }
}
```

Use this class

```
foreach(DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    MyLi li= new MyLi();
    li.DI= di;
    lstdrive.Items.Add(li);
}
```

And get your DriveInfo like this

```
    DriveInfo drive = (lstdrive.SelectedItem as MyLi).DI;
```

Comment: Error 3 Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'System.IO.DriveInfo'